# Appending text to an already existing file at a specific location

Tags: java, netbeans, io, java-8, netbeans-8

I am programming a game for a project and it is coming along smoothly but I have a slight problem, it uses a text file to save which achievements have been unlocked after the program closes, and I do not know how to edit it. While I could rewrite the entire thing using some checks to see what has been unlocked and then putting Y's in the rewrite using if else statements, and then replace it, this would take a large number of lines of code and not as reliable as on the spot writing the achievement, and probably be, although not that badly, more resource intensive, than to replace text at the desired line, into the text file.

so given this structure (number is attached to achievement, letter below tells my program whether it is unlocked or not, N means no Y means yes) if I unlocked achievement 2 for example, how would I search a text file that looks like this...

```
01
N
02
N
03
N
04
N
05
N
06
N
07
N
08
N
09
N
10
N
11
N
12
N
```

for 02 and then edit the line below from N to Y, using java 1.8 code. (the file is called Achievements.txt, and I have a variable called longPath that is the dynamic directory of where the game is stored, so for purposes of sample code the directory will work as

```
(longPath+"\\Achievements.txt")
```

ex.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(longPath+"\\Achievements.txt"));
```

is the start of the code I use to determine in the code which achievements are unlocked (the scanner code is working just fine btw)

edit: rewriting the file is not very feasable, and i am going to bed now, so i will respond tomorrow morning at ~8:10 Estern Time

Comment: nothing because everything i have found is for adding text to the end of a file and for me, for example,  deleting everything up to the 02 and rewriting is almost as bad as completely rewriting the file and replacing it every time an achievement is unlocked @Scary Wombat

Comment: Why are you saving non unlocked achievements. You could simply store only unlocked one and if you do not find the achievement in the file its not unlocked.

Comment: because the scanner structure goes line by line, line one attaches line 2's Y or N to achievement and so on, if i was not storing all of them i could theoretically just add them as they are unlocked, but the structure i use for unlock would have a lot of null pointer exceptions then, so alot of work but this is a feasible answer @Sebastian Walla

Comment: I would go with the rewriting the whole file approach - why do you think it is bad?  How big is this file?

Comment: Its only as big as the example, but i cannot just use \n, because then the text file actually contains a \n, i have to use  a structure that looks like this

            writer.write("01");
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("N");
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("02");
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("Y");
            writer.newLine();...(24 of these, plus initialisation lines and if/else's wrapping each print of "N" or "Y")

@ScaryWombat

Comment: Andrew, I have no idea what you mean

Comment: Do you mean that \n is as actual chars in the file but not as a line break?

Comment: Yes, that is how it shows up in the text file @SebastianWalla

Comment: Ya that's because the website took out my code formatting :| after each semicolon is a line break @ScaryWombat

Comment: If you are simply replacing `N` with `Y` i.e. not writing extra information then RandomAccesFile should work for you

Comment: Thank you @ScaryWombat! this is exactly what i was looking for. If you make this the answer I can close the thread.

Comment: You should use `java.io.RandomAccessFile`. It allows you to read,write and skip bytes

Comment: Thanks Andrew, see my answer

Comment: Yes This was mentioned by now both you and ScaryWombat, thank you both, as it was exactly what i was looking for. @JaySmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply replacing N with Y i.e. not writing extra information then RandomAccesFile should work for you

see this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/randomaccessfile_writechars.htm) for an example of writeChars

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this article: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/

According to it, when you instantiate a new FileWriter class, there is a constructor where you can set a boolean to 'true' in order for it to append to a file rather than overwrite it.

For example:

```
File file = new File(longPath+"\\Achievements.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
fw.write("This string should append to the end of the file");
```

I'm unable to test this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is exactly what I have been finding. I need to be able to wright in the middle of the file :| if you know how to do that, that is what I need. @A. Cucci